# Can a power supply incorrectly shutdown cause my graphics card to blow?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, power

After someone unplugged my pc and rearranged the cords, I cannot get it to work on any monitor. I got a No Signal error so I had someone replace the graphics card which was blown. After this fix, he returned my pc to me and w went to plug my cables in again and I noticed that my power supply was ON. This makes me believe that they carelessly unplugged the power cord while power supply was still on because I still am receiving the same error messages No Signal. He shows me he had it working with a temporary graphics card but what could have possibly gone wrong from this?

Comment: Since someone rearranged the cords did you select the proper input source on the monitor? Have you checked if the cables are properly connected? How do you know the graphics card was blown?

Answer (score 3):

Toggling the ON/OFF switch on the back of power supply is no different than unplugging the cord. It just disconnects the power, there's no graceful shutdown circuitry etc. Your problems are not related to this.